# BxSlider does not show anything

Tags: slider, bxslider

iam using these codes in my website to make a bxsilder

```
<script src="js/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider1').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade'

        });

  });

</script>

                  <div id="slider1">
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="images/thumbnails/slide1.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="images/thumbnails/slide2.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="images/thumbnails/slide3.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <img src="images/thumbnails/slide4.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbs">
                      <a href=""><img src="images/thumbnails/slide1-thumb.png" /></a>
                      <a href=""><img src="images/thumbnails/slide2-thumb.png" /></a>
                      <a href=""><img src="images/thumbnails/slide3-thumb.png" /></a>
                      <a href=""><img src="images/thumbnails/slide4-thumb.png" /></a>
                    </div>

                  </div>
```

---

CSS

```
#slider1{
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.slide {
    width:500px;
    height:350px;
}
.slide img {
    width:500px;
    height:350px;
}

.thumbs {
    width:125px;
    height:75px;
}
```

But nothing appear in the page! except prev & next words
what's wrong with this code?

---

the post is refused because of this message "Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly."
so that iam repeating these words till it's accepted!

"Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly."
"Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly."

Answer (score 0):

I tested you code with bxslider un jquery - ir works "fine". Are You sure, You have Your images correctly added?

Test Your site with Chrome Developer tools, look into Networking and Console - does it shows any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Are the paths to the 2 .js files correct?  That is, do you have a folder named "js" with the two files in there?  Or did you just copy/paste the code from web examples??